# The -t option cannot be used in iptables-restore

Tags: linux, iptables, restore

I got this error when I want to restore my iptables rules from file.

```
iptables-restore v1.4.21: The -t option (seen in line 5) cannot be used in iptables-restore.

Error occurred at line: 5
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

There is my iptables:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o lxcbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

I cannot do it without -t option.

Comment: FWIW: It's can be helpful to use the `iptables` program to add single rules and then look at the output of `iptables-save` afterwards to see the resulting ruleset.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved it:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [95:5492]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [48:3648]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o lxcbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```